# how to remove adds from youtube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

i am trying to chop youtube video using jquery below code but in this videos adds are displaying.

```
               <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://localhost/YoutubeChop/video/chop.swf" width="900" height="440">
                <param name="flashvars" value="vurl=lUcRiho-a7Q" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
```

[image]

anyone suggest me for removing adds from you tube videos. using above code.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           remove Youtube adds
// @namespace      youtubetads
// @version        1.1
// @author         FDisk
// @description    Remove youtube ads from the right side of the screen and from the embeded video
// @include        http://*.youtube.com/watch?*
// @include        http://youtube.com/watch?*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @require        http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/jquery.flash.js
// @require        http://usocheckup.redirectme.net/74961.js
// ==/UserScript==

//Check for updates

$('#homepage-sidebar-ads').remove();

$('#google_companion_ad_div, #watch-channel-brand-div, #watch-channel-brand-div').remove();
var video = 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/'+$('#watch-mfu-button').attr('data-video-id');
$('#watch-player').empty().flash(
    { 
        height: 1280, 
        width: 720,
        src : video+'?version=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;fs=1&amp;hd=1'           
    }
);
```

source: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/74961
Else plugins look for browser plugins like adBlock+

Comment: @Alen.Toma Its a 5 years old answer. I am assuming the container id would have changed. But the fundamental idea should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try add value to cookie([source](https://lifehacker.com/disable-ads-on-youtube-by-enabling-a-youtube-experiment-1171802208))

document.cookie="VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=oKckVSqvaGw; path=/; domain=.youtube.com";

Now works, but behaviour can be changed in future